# How to set today's date and time when pressing a button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, timestamp

I've been following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fj3ALXI90-Q

But I want the date and time displayed in another way.
 This is what I want to happen when I press the button:

```
8/31/2019 9:49:23
```

But this is what displays 2019-08-31 14.45.29 
which I know it's not too far from what I want, but it still isn't the way I want it displayed. Heres the code. I Would appreciate if I could get the whole code so I just can copy and paste due to my lack of knowledge in coding.

```
function setNow() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Just format the column according to your preferred type?

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
new Date()
```

try using:

```
Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+5", "M/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss");
```

see: **https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)**